# What does the -lc option of Intel C++ compiler do?

Tags: c++, icc

I have a Makefile that uses the Intel C++ compiler. It passes the -lc option to icpc when linking the program.
What does this option do exactly?
The code can be compiled without it as well, but I get a slightly larger executable then.

Comment: Isn't that just for linking against libc?

Comment: Yes, but when I check the linked libraries using ldd I get the same result with and without the -lc option. libc is linked in both cases, but the size of the executable is not the same.